# Insert DataTable Directly to PostGres Database through ODBC

Tags: c#, .net, database, postgresql

I have a problem I am an average developer of .net applications as I was working in PHP earlier.

I want to insert a populated DataTable directly to Database through ODBC in .net language is C#

Can anyone please help me doing this .

Thank you so much

```
if (_DataTable1.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            int j=0;
            for(int i =0 ; i < _DataTable1.Rows.Count ; i ++){                   
                query = "Select * from Cards where ecode='" + _DataTable1.Rows[i]["ecode"] + "'";
                _DataTable2 = CentralConn.Select(query);
                if (_DataTable2.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    _DataTableUpdate.Rows.Add(DUpdateRow);
                    foreach (string name in Enum.GetNames(typeof(LocalToCentralFields)))
                    {
                        _DataTableUpdate.Rows[j][name] = _DataTable1.Rows[i][name];
                    }
                    j++;
                }
                else {
                    _DataTableInsert.Rows.Add(DInsertRow);
                    foreach (string name in Enum.GetNames(typeof(LocalToCentralFields)))
                    {
                        _DataTableInsert.Rows[j][name] = _DataTable1.Rows[i][name];
                    }
                    j++;
                }


            }
```

CentralConn.TransactionInsertion(_DataTableInsert);

//code for TransactionInsertion

```
public void TransactionInsertion(DataTable DT,string TableName)
    {

        OdbcCommand Command = connection.CreateCommand();
        Command.CommandText = "Insert";
        Transaction = connection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);

        OdbcDataAdapter Adapter = new OdbcDataAdapter();
        Adapter.InsertCommand = new OdbcCommand();



    }
```

I am stuck here a little bit what to do .. Please guide

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [.Net Data Provider for Postgresql](http://npgsql.projects.pgfoundry.org/exampleprograms.html)

And more specifically at the function

```
// Setups the insert command.
public void insertCmd()
{
    string insertQuery = "INSERT INTO npdata VALUES (@key, @ndata)";
    NpAdapter.InsertCommand = new NpgsqlCommand(insertQuery, conn);

    NpParam = NpAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@key", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Text);
    NpParam.SourceColumn = "key";
    NpParam.SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Current;

    NpParam = NpAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@ndata", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Bigint);
    NpParam.SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Current;
    NpParam.SourceColumn = "ndata";

}
```

Comment: The application which I am working was written in vb6 the purpose of that application was to synchronize electronic cards generated on different gates to the central database . I have rewritten the code in C# using .net 4.0.